# Is Nikon D60 reliable?

Tags: nikon

I'm a total beginner and was given a Nikon D60 camera with Nikon DX AF-S 18-55mm 1:3.5-5.6G lens.

Is this camera reliable?  Should I sell it and get another one?  I really don't know much about cameras.

Comment: It really depends on what previous experience you have with Cameras, what you know about cameras. Etc. Since you're a beginner it's a good camera to start off on. It'll give you space to learn what you're doing, how to use it, and being a relatively older lower-mid range DSLR it'll actually force you to improve your skill to get the best shots out of it.

Comment: If I was a beginner and was given that camera, I would start to learn a maximum of things 'til I'm stuck in my progression... I think you should do the same... Then, if you're in love with photography like many of people here, you'll consider upgrading/changing regarding your new skills and knowledge...

Comment: As for reliability, not really sure, I'm a Canon shooter and don't know that much about the older Nikons. What about it concerned you?

Comment: I have problems with the pictures coming out dark.  And taking pictures at night and my zoom seems terrible...  Maybe I need another lens?

Comment: @Samuel The D60, like most DSLRs, requires a little more skill to use than a point-and-shoot camera or the camera on your phone. The payoff is that when used properly it can be used to take photos those others might not be capable of producing. If you can find an experienced photographer to look at your D60 and eliminate the possibility of a problem with the camera then you can apply yourself to learning how to use the advanced tool you've been given.

Answer (score 4):

That's a fine camera. It was Nikon's entry-level model when it came out in 2008, and it replaced the D40 and D40X, the former of which was a top-selling DSLR for many years straight.

In general, it's plenty reliable, but a) like all DSLRs, it does have a lot of moving parts and b) like all mass-produced electronics, there are sometimes duds. Are you experiencing a particular problem that makes you ask this? If not, don't worry.

It's also several years out of date. Nothing wrong with that, but in particular, its resale value will be low. It's still a capable camera, though, so unless money is no object, it doesn't make much sense to sell it. You should use it to learn the basics, and when you get to the point where you are ready for something else, you will know — and then you could pass it along to someone else and continue the favor you've received.

The D60 was replaced by two lines, the more-basic D3xxx line and the slightly higher D5xxx line. One can get the D3200 for under $500 with lens, and the D3300 for under $600. And I see used D3000s going for as low as $100, so I don't think you'd get more than that selling yours unless you sucker someone. But all of these cameras are perfectly capable despite their age, and in some sense worth much more than they can be sold for. So, again, I'd really suggest getting the value you can out of it, unless you already *know* that you're ready to put serious money into photography. In which case you might want to start with a newer body, which will be faster, have a nicer LCD screen, and be better in low light. And also in that case, upgraded lenses — a whole world to learn in itself.

Comment: I honestly just don't know how to use it...I can take pictures but doing all the settings for a proper photo is confusing me.  This is literally my first camera besides the one on my smartphone.

Comment: The free application here helped me understanding the basics : http://camerasim.com/apps/camera-simulator/

Comment: @Samuel Maybe you should first download and read [the D60 manual](https://support.nikonusa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/14511), if it's not included anymore?